# multiprocessing.Array Segmentation fault

Tags: python, memory, ctypes, python-multiprocessing

```
from multiprocessing import Value
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray
from ctypes import addressof, c_char

array = RawArray(c_char, b'shirt')
array_length = array._length_
result_address = Value('i', 0)
result_address.value = addressof(array)
print((array._type_*array_length).from_address(result_address.value).value)
```

In one process I pass `result_address` of type `multiprocessing.Value` to a child process, which then creates an array in shared memory and writes its address back to `result_address`. Basically I want to share a bytestring created in child process with the parent process without using `multiprocessing.Manager` as it's only a bytestring and it can (?) be managed in shared memory.

Also this `(array._type_*array_length).from_address()` maybe creates the array in memory again, how do I just read the c array in python string without creating another array?

The code even does not work in single process and produces `Segmentation fault`.

Comment: I'm guessing it's probably due to what is mentioned in the **Note** [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes) in the documentation.

Comment: @martineau They say only something about pointers. I do save an address location in shared memory, but its an address of an array also in shared memory. Nevertheless it does not work in a single process.

Comment: Try making sure the `Value` can hold a 4-byte pointer by using an `'L'` typecode instead of `'i'` who's minimum size only 2 bytes. You may need 8 bytes for 64-bit systems.

Comment: @martineau thanks now it works in single process, but as you suggested it does not work when multiprocessing. Although I don't understand why, when I allocate the Array in shared memory.

Comment: If it worked single process by making it 4-bytes, try making it 8-bytes and see if that helps the multiprocessing. Seems reasonable that addressing shared memory might require a larger address in order to be accessible from any of them.